# The parameter "id" must be defined

Tags: php, arrays, json, symfony, pimcore

When I try to access my subpage, this error pops-out

```
The parameter "id" must be defined.

> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\
InvalidArgumentException
in var/cache/dev/Container6do1xtb/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php (line 4787)
appDevDebugProjectContainer->getParameter('id')
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php (line 40)
Controller->getParameter('id')
in src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php (line 22)
//        $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(10);//        $this->view->paginator  = $paginator;    }    public function blogarticleAction(){        $this->view->blogarticle = \Pimcore\Model\DataObject\Blogpost::getById($this->getParameter("id"));    }}
DefaultController->blogarticleAction()
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php (line 151)
HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php (line 68)
HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php (line 202)
Kernel->handle(object(Request))
in web/app.php (line 55)
```

Code I used to do this

default.html.php

```
<div class="post-preview">
    <a href="<?= $this->path('blogpost', [
                    'id' => $blogpost-> getId(),
                    'title' => $blogpost -> getTitle(),
            ]); ?>">
```

defaultcontroller.php

```
 public function blogarticleAction($id){
     $this->view->blogarticle = \Pimcore\Model\DataObject\Blogpost::getById($this->getParam("id"));
}
```

RegEx set up:

[image]

ofcourse I created `blogarticle.html.php` in the same folder as `default.html.php`

Comment: It looks like your container does not have any parameter `id`defined. What does`id` refer to ( in the controller ) ?

Comment: It refer to  \Pimcore\Model\DataObject\Blogpost

Comment: When im trying to go the page it automaticly display generate id 5

Comment: `$this->getParameter("id")` will look for a parameter named `id`into the container. If it's a blogpost id, you have to pass it as parameter of the action

Comment: Yep.  Assuming this is a regular Symfony app (which I'm not sure of) then blogarticleAction($id) would do the trick.

Comment: Still the same ... https://imgur.com/a/qSo2irJ

Comment: when i checked what GET know with var_dump($_GET);
die(); it returned array(0) { }

Comment: Update your controller code in your question.  The linked image still shows that you using getParameter.  https://symfony.com/doc/master/routing.html#creating-routes

Comment: But when im changing getParam instead of getParameter this random error pops out                                                                             Attempted to call an undefined method named "getParam" of class "AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$id` from action, not from container

```
public function blogarticleAction($id){
     $this->view->blogarticle = \Pimcore\Model\DataObject\Blogpost::getById($id);
}
```

`$this->getParam("id")` Will look in the container a parameter named `id`, which is not what you want

You should read https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html which explains about route parameters